# C++/MFC - Device Manager is finished detecting devices?

Tags: c++, windows-7, mfc, hid, device-manager

I have an application that programs our manufactured HID devices during initialization. The devices are already plugged in to the USB ports and this program autoruns as soon as the system boots.  On Windows XP, this has been working fine and we are now updating with support for Windows 7.  The problem I am seeing is that the load time for Windows 7 is substantially faster and the application starts before all devices are actually found in device manager.  If I set an arbitrary timeout (ie: 30 seconds) in the code before starting the program, that is enough time for device manager to do it's thing and all devices are properly detected and programmed during startup.

Question:  Rather than setting some sort of static timeout, is there a programmatical way (using C++ and MFC) to determine when Windows 7 device manager has finished detecting all currently plugged in devices?